# Bootstrap col-xs-5 at center with col-xs-3.5 at both sides

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create this structure

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3.5"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-5"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3.5"></div>
</div>
```

As bootstrap column doesn't supports fractional column, i tried to accomplish this using nesting:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <!-- Using nesting column-->
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
</div>
```

But now there is space between the content of center column and right/left column. Is there any way to center the content of left/right column as well(covering space created by offset).

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xktpp2hd/)

**Edit**

Here's how it looks now

[image: How it looks now]

Here's what i need

[image: What i need]

Comment: What mean `col-xs-3.5`?  i know only the grid system base on 12 column and not fractional column

Comment: Yes i know, That is for providing an idea what i want. I know bootstrap column doesn't supports fractional column, so i tried nesting.

Comment: Would [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/xktpp2hd/2/) be an option?

Comment: I don't get it your question

Comment: Updated my question for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have Bootstrap with has much columns as you wish. Since you want half column; you could do a 24 columns Bootstrap And do it like  `col-xs-7 col-xs-10 col-xs-7`
Have a look there -> [Customize Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)